# Communication between instances in Cloud Foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry, hazelcast

Is there a possibility to communicate between multiple instances of an application deployed to Cloud Foundry? 
I checked the Cloud Foundry API but I couldn't find any mention of this subject.
I already tried Hazelcast but unfortunately, my Cloud Foundry provider doesn't support Multicasting, so I would have to know the IP addresses of every other instance in order to connect.

I think I can't be the only one interested in this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you use a messaging service (like RabbitMQ) to communicate between instances of applications. You can also store shared information in a database service or any remote location outside the file system.

It is generally not a good practice to build applications that require this type of communication in the cloud. Each instance should ideally be able to run independently and be stateless.

Comment: Thanks @ram-vennam. I agree with you that such applications should use a different architecture or not be deployed to the cloud. In my case, each Instance has a `Scheduler` (schedule-modul in Node.js or annotation in JavaEE). For a proof of concept, the scheduler just writes a value into a database once a minute. But with 2..n instances I don't want to have 2..n entries each minute, so I'm looking for something to synchronise the instances so only one of all the instances writes to the database - possibly a different instance every minute due to load or availability.

Comment: I see that RabbitMQ is a service available in Cloud Foundry so I'll give it a try. Thank you very much for the idea. I think I will try to implement the "Work queues" pattern of RabbitMQ.

Comment: I have used Redis PUB/SUB for a similar scenario in CF.  All app instances register to a specific Redis channel and broadcast messages over it. It could get more complicated if your distributed problem requires synchronisation of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

If you can programmatically access the ip addresses, you can build up the Hazelcast Config object and use that to setup your cluster. You can then rely on tcp-ip discovery.

pseudo code:

```
List<String> ipAddresses = cloudfoundry.getIps()
Config config = new Config();
config.getJoinConfig().getIpDiscovery().addMembers(ipAddresses)
HazelcastInstance hz = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
```

You can even load your existing Hazelcast XML configuration and enhance it on the fly using the XmlConfigBuilder.

Comment: Thank you @pveentjer. That was my plan but in Cloud Foundry every instance obtains an arbitrary/undeterminable IP address upon starting. So the IP addresses are unknown to the other instances. That's why I relied on Multicasting - which is unfortunately not active / blocked by my application cloud provider. By the way, I wanted to use Vert.x as the EventBus for the communication. It supports Hazelcast natively and is very easy to setup.

Comment: Most CF operators, especially public ones running untrusted apps, will disable direct container to container communication.  While direct container to container communication might allow you do to some interesting things, if a bad person could run an app on the same CF installation it would allow them to do interesting things to you as well.

Answer (score 1):

There might be occasions where the instances need to communicate amongst themselves instead of using an external component to gain efficiency or avoid dependency. One possibility is to use gorouter itself with specific instance id in http with below header.
X-Cf-App-Instance=app-uuid:instanceno-integer

Other option which I am yet to explore is explained in this link
https://ict.swisscom.ch/2018/05/container-networking-with-cloud-foundry/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29878326)